# (C#) Reading a part of a line

Tags: c#, text, line, streamreader

I have a text file and within it, it looks like:

```
xxxx:value
```

All I want to read is the value, 
I've tried to manipulate:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
            {
                String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

But I haven't had much luck in doing that, any help would be brilliant.

Comment: What's the problem that you're having? It doesn't look like you've tried to implement that logic at all.

Comment: I don't have my tests saved, but that was my starting point.

Comment: `ReadToEnd` does what its name suggests: read everything from the current position to the end. It's no surprise that it doesn't work this way.

Comment: The `Split` answers below assume that `value` does not have a colon in it. If a colon is a valid character in `value`, then you'll want to use [IndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and [Substring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to loop through each line and split each line...  Probably should check that each line isn't null and that it does contain a colon...  but that could be unnecessary depending on your data...

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
                {
                    while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        String line = sr.ReadLine();
                        if (line != null && line.Contains(":"))
                            Console.WriteLine(line.Split(':')[1]);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   using System;
    using System.IO;

    class Test
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            try
            {
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("TestFile.txt"))
                {
                    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    string[] array = line.Split(':');                    
                    Console.WriteLine(array[1]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `string.Split()`:

```
Console.WriteLine(line.Split(':')[1]);
```